# Limiting Downtime on Map Services Shared Directly to ArcGIS Portal While Doing Schema Changes

Tags: arcgis-portal

I have a number of feature layers shared directly to Portal for ArcGIS.

If I need to update the schema of these feature classes, can I do so while the feature service is still in use, or must I somehow stop it?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  If the answer to the first one is Yes, then your second is unnecessary.

Comment: I expect the answer to both questions is no, if by "keeping the layer in my web maps" you mean using the service while it is being maintained.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that you need to stop the service.  Is this a Hosted Layer or a layer associated with a data store?  How big and complex is the layer?